# Android: Issue in calculating distance using Location manager

Tags: android, locationmanager

Currently I am working on an application, where I want to calculate distance a vehicle travels. My requirement is while driving car, my Android device should calculate total distance I traveled and send this information to server. In order to do this, I used Android's location manager api, set criteria and used getBestProvider. This way we can either use GPS or Network to get latitude and longitude. The following is the code snippet of this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,30000,5, this);
```

onLocationChanged() call back method provide latitude and longitude every time. We always store previous coordinates and when we get new coordinates we find the distance between the two using distanceBetween() api. The following is the code snippet of this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                    findLatLongDistance(location);
}

private void findLatLongDistance(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                  Date date = new Date();
                  TimeStamp2 = sdf.format(date);

                              getSavedLatLong();//get lat and long from preference
                          Location locationB = new Location("point B"); 

                          locationB.setLatitude(location.getLatitude()); 
                          locationB.setLongitude(location.getLongitude()); 

                          Location locationA = new Location("point A"); 

locationA.setLatitude(prelat_val);  //lat from pref                       locationA.setLongitude(prelong_val);  //long from pref

                          if(prelat_val>0.0 && prelong_val>0.0){
                              Toast.makeText(LocationService.this,"Location Odometer Sum "+odometer_sum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                  float distance2 = getDistance(prelat_val,prelong_val,location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                                  odometer_sum = odometer_sum + (distance2/1000);
                                  Toast.makeText(LocationService.this,"Lat "+prelat_val+"Long "+prelong_val+"Sum "+odometer_sum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                          }

                        saveData(lat,lng,odometer_sum);
            }catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }


public float getDistance(double d, double e, double f, double g) {

            float [] dist = new float[2];

            Location.distanceBetween(d,e,f, g, dist);
          return dist[0] ;
      }
```

This is the list of issue that we face here:

1. The location it provide is not accurate. There is a difference of about 300-400 metres while we testing this app in 5 km distance
2. When the mobile is in same location for long time, it always provide different latitude and longitude. If you check above code snippet, in requestLocationUpdates(), we are setting 30 seconds time interval and 5m distance. Here what we thought is, if my mobile device move 5m distance AND if it cross 30 seconds interval, it will provide new latitude and longitude. But what really happens is, it provide coordinates every 30 seconds irrespective of device movement. I am not sure how to fix this issue.
3. While device is moving, how to get accurate value. Do I need to do some more things in the code?

I really spend so many hours trying various options. But I feel I am missing something here. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance..

Thanks,

Comment: According to your criteria. it will take the network triangulation values. use gps provider directly and check latitude and longitude. locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,30000,5, this);

Comment: There is one another issue I am facing as mentioned above. When the mobile is in same location for long time, it always provide different latitude and longitude. How to control this issue? This can be fixed with different criteria setting or with some other option? Please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Your minTime value in requestLocationUpdates() is 30seconds. Thats too long for an app that tries to calculate accurate distances. I have used `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 5, locationListener);`
in my code for long and I get accurate updates. Though this drains the battery very fast. So you would have to try different values to strike a balance between accuracy and battery life and see what suits your app